# NSDateFormator in iphone doubts

Tags: iphone

Ha ii,I know how to formate a date in iphone,but i have to set the date as given by the image below.My code is 
[image]

```
    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];

    //Create the dateformatter object

    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    //Set the required date format

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:mm:dd"];

    //Get the string date

    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    //Display on the console

   // NSLog(str);

    //Set in the lable

    [_lbldateLabel setText:str];
```

How to modify my above code to get the current date as given by the image?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    //Set the required date format

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd/yy"];

    //Get the string date

    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: it works great,but i want to display year in the upper portion and then date and month just below the year,as mention the image above.thankz.

Comment: If you want to reorder the components, it shouldn't be that cryptic. If you want a string with just the month set the format to @"MMM".  call stringFromDate: then change the format to another component and get that string the same way.

Comment: how to seperate the string ?NSArray* components = [initialString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];is this the code for doing this?